# Orientdb getVertices() returing Vertex for any label present in database

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1, orientdb2.2

I am using **Orientdb 2.2.10**.

What I want to achieve?

I want to get a vertex of a particular vertexType
- e.g vertexType = 'Person'.

**My graphdb is indexed with unique key('uid')**.

What I am doing to achieve it?

- **getVertices(lable, []iKey, []iValue)**
- **I am getting the desire vertex**

**what is problem with this method?** :-

- I am getting the desire vertex even when I provide **any label(which is present in the database) name**

**e.g:-**

- I want to get a vertex of **vertextype** = 'Person' having **uid** = 'ram'
- I am getting this vertex even when I provide any **label** (e.g "Relation") which is present in database.

Is this a bug or I am doing something wrong?

Thanks..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replicated your structure.

[image: enter code here]

I have tried with this code

```
String [] keys=new String[]{"uid"};
String [] values=new String[]{"ram"};
Iterable<Vertex> it= g.getVertices("Person", keys, values);
for(Vertex v:it){
    System.out.println(v.getId());
    System.out.println(v.getProperty("uid"));
}
```

and I obtained

**#21:0
ram**

while with

```
String [] keys=new String[]{"uid"};
String [] values=new String[]{"ram"};
Iterable<Vertex> it= g.getVertices("Relational", keys, values);
for(Vertex v:it){
    System.out.println(v.getId());
    System.out.println(v.getProperty("uid"));
}
```

I got nothing.

Hope it helps.

Comment: when I again tried it without doing indexing on 'uid' , I am also getting nothing. But with indexing on 'uid' I am getting result

Comment: please try it with indexing on 'uid'

Comment: please have a look at  (https://codepad.co/snippet/638utVcY), code + output result .

Comment: I used these indeces Person.uid UNIQUE  ["uid"]  SBTREE and
Relational.uid  UNIQUE  ["uid"] SBTREE

Comment: your version 2.2.10 ?

Comment: Yes, version 2.2.10. With your code I reproduced your problem. I have created two indices and not one as you. Could you open an issue on github ?

Comment: sure..! So you mean  problem was orientdb bug and not with my code, right?